# Ant deploy to tomcat 7

Tags: ant, tomcat7

I have changed my Tomcat Server from version 6 to 7 and now my ant deploy fails.

At first i had my ant build like the following and got a 403 error

```
<taskdef resource="org/apache/catalina/ant/catalina.tasks" classpathref="x.classpath" />

<target name="tomcatdeploy" depends="tomcatundeploy,war">
  <deploy url="http://localhost/manager/html" username="x" password="x" path="/xx" war="file:x.war"/>                   
</target>
```

I found several sources on the internet an changed the `manager/html` to `manager/text` and added the roles `manager-script` and `admin-script` in the tomcat-user file.

The error I am getting now is

```
  java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
```

I found that this may be because of the size of the .war file which i deploy which is about 250M, but i didn't find a solution how to deploy it to tomcat 7 from ant.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a comprehensive post about this Problem:
http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/catalina-ant-for-tomcat-7.html